# Rails: How to create database schema with ActiveRecord::Schema like in django?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-schema

I like Rails, but I'm not a big fan of migrations.

How can I use the ActiveRecord::Scema tool to create a database without using SQL and without migrations?

I know you use it like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
    create_table :authors do |t|
        t.string :name, :null => false
    end

    add_index :authors, :name, :unique

    create_table :posts do |t|
        t.integer :author_id, :null => false
        t.string :subject
        t.text :body
        t.boolean :private, :default => false
    end

    add_index :posts, :author_id
end
```

But how do you run this?

Please don't recommend to use migrations, because I... simply don't like them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well migrations are the best way to manage the evolutions of your database ;)

However you can directly load a schema.rb into your database if you wish to.

```
rake db:schema:load
```

I wouldn't recomment it however.

Comment: And what kind of file do I need to create?

Comment: This command uses the file `db/schema.rb` which is automatically generated by your migrations (when using them).

Answer (score 2):

try `rake db:schema:load`